# implement an edit button in toolbar (storyboard)

Tags: ios

I'm trying to implement a toolbar button.
In this case an edit button in my view. 
I select the toolbar in the inspector, and I add a button with storyboard. 
I write this method in the viewdidload but something is wrong. the button isn't displayed in the toolbar.

Can somebody help me to make it work?

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
{
     [super viewDidLoad];

     UIBarButtonItem *editButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Birds"
                                                                    style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered 
                                                                   target:self 
                                                                   action:@selector(goToBirdsView:)];

     NSArray *toolbarItems = [NSArray arrayWithObject:editButton];

     self.navigationController.toolbarHidden = NO;
}

-(IBAction)goToBirdsView:(UIButton *)sender 
{
     [self performSegueWithIdentifier:segueToBirdsList sender:self];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
     toolBar = [[UIToolBar alloc]initWithFrame:(As_U_Need)];
    NSMutableArray *barItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    UIBarButtonItem *flexSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]   initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:self action:nil];
        [barItems addObject:flexSpace];

        UIBarButtonItem * editButton= [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Birds" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(goToBirdsView:)];
    [barItems addObject: editButton];

    [toolBar setItems:barItems animated:YES];
    [self.view addSubView:toolBar];

}

-(IBAction)goToBirdsView:(UIButton *)sender 
{
           [self performSegueWithIdentifier:segueToBirdsList sender:self];
}
```

Comment: should i declare :@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIToolbar *toolbar; in my header file?

Comment: if u use ARC then declare it :)

Comment: ok,but i still don't understand why the edit button isn't displayed in the toolbar.

Comment: follow my code , it is programmatically store UIBarButtonItem on ToolBar

Comment: ok,the code works,the toolbar is displayed with the edit button.i use the initWithFrame:(CGRectMake(0, 125, self.view.frame.size.width, 44)),but now i don't know how to connect the action and put the identifier in the segue.